# Java simple regex with hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple. I have meta-data with this format

```
    -key=value
```

I've already split the string at the `=` but I need to take the `-` off. I'm trying to use this function `key.replaceFirst("-", "");` but it doesn't do anything to the string.

I've tried putting `\\` in the regex but that solved nothing.

**Solution:**

I did not say `key = key.replaceFirst("-", "");`

Comment: Don't split; match instead. Use the following regex: `[-=]([a-z]+)`. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/cT3dE1/1). If that's not what you're looking for, could you please [*Edit*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24997309/edit) the question to include more details?

Comment: Try `key = key.replaceFirst("\\s*-", "");`.

Comment: @Ben in eclipse that says invalid escape sequence.

Comment: Show us more of your code because replaceFirst works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign back return value of `replaceFirst` as `String` is immutable object:

```
key = key.replaceFirst("-", "");
```

Comment: @Unihedron: Does `StringBuffer` have `split` and `replaceFirst` methods?

Comment: @Unihedron OP did write "string". - And there wouldn't be any explanation why it would fail on a StringBuffer :-)

Answer (score 3):

[`String.replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) does not replace the string in-place, but returns a replaced string.

You need to assign back the return value:

```
key = key.replaceFirst("-", "");
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, String.replaceFirst does replace the string but it is returned and does not change the original.

Comment: @JamesB, I updated sentence (by adding `in-place`) in the answer to make it clear. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: No problem, apologies if you feel I was being picky.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the string back to it !

```
key = key.replaceFirst("-", "");
System.out.println(key);
```

HTH,
Keshava.